# React/Next.js pre-building pages slows down application?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I current started studying Next.js framework and I had one question.

Lets say I have a dynamic route for user such as `users/profile/[id].js`.

And I try to pre-build them with Static generation. Would not this slow down my app if I will have lets say 1 million users? I tried to use SSR but it is pretty slow too. Plus in documentation it is stated that we should always user Static generation if we know data ahead.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Next.js [static generation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export), then the pages will be rendered once at build-time and generated as static html/css/js which is the best in term of performance at runtime. so no, it wont slow down your app, only the build phase.

As you mention millions of pages, you could take a look at [incremental static generation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration) which allows you to prerender only a portion of your pages and generate other static pages "on demand". This is needed if your build time becomes too big.